# Combining a question with statement

Tags: punctuation, questions

I am confused in whether to use a "?" or"." in this sentence.

Original question:

> Did you take the last test, and yes understood the question that I asked correctly.

Revised question:

> Did you take the test yesterday, and yes did interpret the question that 
>       I asked correctly.

Is the sentence correct? Is a comma the incorrect punctuation to use to combine the question and statement?

Is this a more clear statement:

> Did you take the test yesterday? Also, yes you did interpret the question 
>       that I asked correctly.

Comment: I'm a little lost. Where do you want to use the question mark or the period? What does "and yes understood" mean?

Comment: Short answer is avoid doing it.

Answer (score 2):

Your example sentence is not grammatically correct, which makes your question difficult to answer.

Consider the second part of the sentence by itself. You need the "did you" to make it a question, so you'd have, "Did you yes understood the question that I asked correctly?" The word "yes" does not belong here. It does not fit in the sentence. "Did you understood" is not correct: it should be "did you understand". And it's not clear what "correctly" modifies. Are you asking if the person understood correctly? Or are you stating that you asked correctly? Most readers would assume "correctly" modifies the closest verb, "asked". If the intent is that it modifies "understand", it's unnecessary. We assume "understand" means "correctly understand" unless you specify otherwise.

Perhaps what you mean, then, is, "Did you take the last test and understand the question that I asked?" In that case, you would use a question mark, because it's a question. The fact that the question has two parts doesn't change this. It's not a question combined with a statement. It's a question with two parts.

If you really had a question combined with a statement, normally you should break this into two sentences. "Did you take the last test? I wrote question 5." If you really want to combine them into one sentence, you'd need to turn the statement into a subordinate clause, like, "Did you take the test on which I wrote question five?"

Comment: I see that there is no advantage to my trying to combine a question with statement. Thank you for the help.